# Why does 'user:ID deleted:1 is:question' return undeleted results when reputation is insufficient for correct results?

Tags: discussion, support, search

I have high rep in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+deleted%3A1+is%3Aquestion), so the `user:12102 deleted:1 is:question` returns exactly what I've asked for, a list of my own deleted questions.

But when I repeat the same kind of search with my user ID in sites where I have less than 2k rep, I get a long list of undeleted questions, not what I asked for.

To me, this is unexpected behavior. I'd expect a message of the type "you can't do that" with the same format as the "Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content" message that appears when the search is successful.

[image]

**Question:** Is this unexpected behavior? Does it rise to the level of a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

---

Example of **Expected behavior** on site where I have high rep:

> [image: example of expected behavior]

---

Example of **Unexpected behavior?** on site where I have lower rep (plenty of *undeleted question* with no message indicating that this is not what was requested):

> [image: example of unexpected behavior]

Comment: I have a theory. If you can't use the search function, we ignore it. But that's a guess that explains the behavior, not necessarily the answer.

Comment: @Catija I've added a bounty

Comment: Probably the same thing? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400332/some-deleted-posts-show-up-in-search-results

Comment: [Privileges - access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), with this privilege cames a new search operator available to find your own deleted posts: `deleted:1`.

Comment: Given the fact that the search results [explicitly say **not deleted**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgwJS.png) when using `deleted:#` as someone without the privilege, I'd say that Cat's original "we ignore it" is likely.

Comment: @Nickistired so would "We ignore it, [tag:status-completed]" be a suitable answer? Or perhaps "We ignore it, [tag:status-bydesign]"? To me, "you have low rep, so 'here is a potato'." feels... unresolved.

Comment: Since this is a question rather than a bug report or feature request, neither tag is applicable here.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Ya I just can't tell if this rises to the level of bug-report-tag-worthy. The bountification may attract enough comments to determine if a tag update is warranted.

Comment: The current tags are fine, in my view. The [tag:support] tag can be used on questions where you aren't sure if it's a bug; in fact, [tag:possible-bug] is a synonym.