# Searching for title:"phrase here" (with the quotation marks) returns search results for question and answer bodies if none exist for the title

Tags: bug, status-review, search, title

From the help center's [article on searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> To limit your search to just the title of a question, use `title:` followed by the search term. Likewise, search the body only (exclude the title) with `body:"phrase here"`.

Thus I would expect searching for `title:"phrase here"` would search *only titles* for that exact phrase. However, if no titles match the search, some unexpected behavior occurs:

- The search returns hits based on bodies
- The search returns hits from both questions and answers (despite the top of the search saying, e.g. ["Search options title help please **questions only**"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22help+please%22))
- The search stops looking for the verbatim phrase in quotation marks, and treats each word separately
- The search throws in "title" as a keyword that the bodies have to match

The expected behavior would be returning no results at all; indeed, if the quotation marks are omitted from the search (e.g. `title:keyword`), and no title has the keyword, it works as expected. A similar bug report for searching ignoring an impossible operator can be found here: [Why does 'user:ID deleted:1 is:question' return undeleted results when reputation is insufficient for correct results?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326312/)

---

Examples follow. (All example searches are from Puzzling because I'm too lazy to find equivalent ones on Meta)

A simple example: searching [`title:"joos"`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22joos%22) returns [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92376/a-riley-riddle-to-end-the-year), which has "joos" (and "title") in the body but not the title. Searching [`title:joos`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Ajoos) returns nothing.

Another example: searching [`title:"help please"`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22help+please%22) returns (among other things) [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90828/hoping-for-a-satisfying-conclusion-a-musical-connect-wall), which has "help", "please", and "title" in the question body. All the keywords are apart from each other. The search also returns [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87529/what-is-my-lovers-name/87533#87533), which likewise has "help", "please", and "title" in the body. It *doesn't* return [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52310/help-wanted-pretty-please), which has "help" and "please" but not "title".

And in this case searching [`title:help please`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Ahelp+please) isn't a solution, because that returns e.g. [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36278/time-sensitive-decoding-help-needed) which does *not* contain "help please" in the title (or even "please"). Which is what I'd expect. Removing the quotation marks would be expected to break multiword searches.

As far as I can test, this is broken for `body:"phrase here"`. Searching [`body:"combination Med School"`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22combination+Med+School%22) returns [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/76118/), which has "body" as well as the other keywords, just out of order. I can't find any words which only exist in titles to test that particular part of the bug, however.